# Change AD password from MVC3 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory, wif, adfs2.0

I am building a MVC3 web application with WIF and ADFS 2.0. What I want to do is to provide a change password-function for my users, they will be changing their AD password from this web application. Since I am in the development stage, I have to be able to change AD password from my development computer (outside domain). Later, permissions will be delegated to a user that runs the service with sufficient access.

I want to do this role based, without typing in username and password and I can't seem to find any resources which points me in the right direction.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't anything specific in WIF or AD FS for changing user passwords. You'll have to use the standard AD functionality provided in the `System.DirectoryServices` namespace.

Here's some sample code for changing a password in AD:

```
internal UserPrincipal GetUser(string userName)
{
    PrincipalContext principalContext = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YourADController",
                                               "YourADContainer",
                                               "ADAdminUser", "ADAdminPassword");

    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(principalContext, userName);

    return user;
}

internal void ResetPassword(string userName, string newPassword)
{
    try
    {
        //
        // Update normal AD attributes
        //
        UserPrincipal user = GetUser(userName);
        user.SetPassword(newPassword);
    }
    catch (PasswordException)
    {
        throw new Exception("Password does not meet complexity requirements");
    }
}

internal void SetPassword(string userName, string oldPassword, string newPassword)
{
    try
    {
        //
        // Update normal AD attributes
        //
        UserPrincipal user = GetUser(userName);
        user.ChangePassword(oldPassword, newPassword);
    }
    catch (PasswordException)
    {
        throw new Exception("Password does not meet complexity requirements");
    }
}
```